# Equation: $(x^2-9y^2)^2=33y+16$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to know the solution of the equation $(x^2-9y^2)^2=33y+16$ in positive integers.
I know it has solution $(\pm2;0)$ but I can't prove that it doesn't have other solutions.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove a limit on the number of solutions like so:

Rewrite $(x^2-9y^2)^2=33y+16$ as $x^2 = (3y)^2 \pm \sqrt {33y+16}$.

For sufficiently large $y$,

$$(3y-1)^2 \lt (3y)^2 - \sqrt {33y+16} \lt (3y)^2 \lt (3y)^2 + \sqrt {33y+16} \lt (3y+1)^2$$

hence $\sqrt {(3y)^2 \pm \sqrt {33y+16}}$ cannot be an integer for sufficiently large $y$.

Comment: May I add on this? "Sufficiently large" $y$ is when 
$$\begin{align*}(3y)^2+\sqrt{33y+16}<&(3y)^2+6y+1=(3y)^2+\sqrt{36y^2+12y+1}\\
33y+16<&36y^2+12y+1\\
36y^2-21y-15>&0\\
y>&\frac{21+\sqrt{21^2-4\times36\times(-15)}}{2\times36} = 1\end{align*}$$So the other answer had found out all the solutions.

Comment: Ah, that large?  I guess knowing what we know we can start from:
  
For $y > 2$,$$0 < 36y^2 - 45y - 15$$
$$33y+16 < 36y^2 - 12y+1$$
$$33y+16 < (6y-1)^2 < (6y+1)^2$$
$$\sqrt {33y+16} < 6y-1 < 6y+1$$
$$-(6y-1) < -\sqrt {33y+16} < 0 < \sqrt {33y+16} < 6y+1$$  etc.

Answer (score 0):

It does have other solutions. 
(4, 1) for example

Comment: the solution of the equation should be in positive integers

Comment: I guess (4,1) was the only valid one in the list I had mentioned. My bad.